# Fedora 13: How to uncheck install boot loader on /dev/sda?

Tags: installation, fedora, fedora-13

I want to install Fedora 13 with boot loader on its own partition (not on MBR). Option "Install boot loader on /dev/sda" is not available. How can i do this?
Is this option available in Fedora 14?

I am selecting option "Use Free Space"

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick the option for advanced bootloader configuration.

Comment: I have installed Windows XP already. I have 80 GB free space, can you please give me some example "Custom Partition Layout"? As when "Use Free Space" option is selected, it does not give option for selecting bootloader.

Comment: That's because it's a few screens or so after.